# FOSOAuthServerBundle invalid client

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

I tried to follow this blog

[FOSOAuth Tutorials](https://bitgandtter.blog/category/personal/):

I followed all through his explanations except that I change this:

```
service:
    user_provider: fos_user.user_manager
```

to

```
service:
    user_provider: fos_user.user_provider.username
```

When I tried to get the auth on oauth/v2/token it tells me that my client is invalid.

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
```

This is my route:

```
http://lom_api.local/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token?client_id=22fkr98hnts08ws8o4w8cg4wooogo8ck0gkkcowo4osgssskww&client_secret=e28421fn2aogcg0ccg4ggkk8oowsg840k4okc0wcc08c048sw&grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin
```

What might be causing this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client ID is wrong. It shoudl be 
1_22fkr98hnts08ws8o4w8cg4wooogo8ck0gkkcowo4osgssskww

or

2_22fkr98hnts08ws8o4w8cg4wooogo8ck0gkkcowo4osgssskww

The first number is the row id on the Token table.

Comment: I think (not sure because is quite long since I realized this) that if you create the client using the console you get the full client_id on the command output.

Comment: Yeah, my fault, i actually just used the random_id without realizing the $client->getPublicId() concats id and the random_id. Thank you very much!